# In Symfony2 how can I append a date to the assetic filenames

Tags: symfony, assetic

I'm using assetic with symfony and I'd like to append a timestamp or date string to the end of the filenames it creates.

The purpose of this is to have more control over browser caching, so every time I run assetic:dump, all my compiled assets will have a new file name and users browsers will download the new file.

Is this the best way to prevent browsers using old (cached) asset files?

If it is, how do I append the timestamp to the filenames?

Comment: try something like `<script src="{{ asset('js/script.js') }}?a=123" type="text/javascript"></script>`. You can also make this a random number or a build number based on your application / needs. I dont have a Symfony project to hand to test this, so you'll need to test it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest, in order to have control over browser's cache, do the following:

**app/config/config.yml**

```
framework:
   templating:
       assets_version: %assets_version%
```

This setting will make assetic append `?vX` to asset url (`X` is your `%asset_version%` parameter).

**parameters.yml**

```
parameters:
    assets_version: 1
```

You need to change your asset version each time you want to deploy new version of assets and make user browser to fetch new content.

There is also [AssetsVersionBundle](https://github.com/kachkaev/KachkaevAssetsVersionBundle) which adds command to increase `%assets_version%` for you. Just type

```
app/console assets_version:increase
```

Documentation of this bundle covers assets versioning issue pretty well