# Symfony serve assetics directly

Tags: symfony, assetic

Hei @all,

I've got a annoying problem using assetics inside my dev environment..

I'm currently building a backend UI using ReactJS.
The CSS/JS files always get cached by the browser. Does anyone knows how to serve such files directly without dumping assetics?

It is very annoying to clear the cache all the time during development ..

I know, I could use the `assetic:watch` command to dumping assetics automatic, but the problem is the browser cache ..

The browser I use is Google Chrome ..

– Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `assetic`, use `gulp` or eventually gassetic: https://github.com/romanschejbal/gassetic

Comment: You need some "cache busting" I believe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1)** You can open developer tools in Chrome and **disable cache** : [image]

> **2)** If you need update your cache only one time, you can press **Ctrl+F5**
>
> **3)** And you can one more trick:  **add to your site adress some get parameter**, ex:  *site.com?a=blabla*
>   and browser will reload cached files

**USE ASSETIC VERSIONS:**
Try this: you can set version for your assets , but version changes manually
[In Symfony2 how can I append a date to the assetic filenames](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28034456/in-symfony2-how-can-i-append-a-date-to-the-assetic-filenames)

Comment: Thanks, but these tricks I already know .. :/
Is there any symfony bundle to add the current timestamp to assetic outputs, like "main.css?123456"?